# Trying to display scrollable text in a fixed-sized container

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I'm trying to show some info in a TextView that's inside a ScrollView. The length of the text will usually vary, but I want the TextView to keep the same height even if it's empty (if the text is too long, the user has to scroll). I have the scrolling part, but if the text is too short, the TextView wraps around it and shrinks. How can I avoid that? Or alternately, how can I get the look and behaviour I'm looking for using something different? I've tried using a read-only, multi-line EditText instead of the TextView and removing the ScrollView, but I couldn't make the EditText read-only unless I set the "enabled" property as false, and doing that doesn't let the user scroll.

The main device I'm using to test my app uses Android 4.4.4 (KitKat), and I also tested on version 4.1.2 (Jelly Bean).

Here's the code for the layout; the TextView I'm having problems with is ***TextViewInfo1***:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayoutMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <TextView
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:id="@+id/TextViewLabelName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/name" />
        <TextView
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:id="@id/TextViewName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_textview"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_textview"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/TextViewLabelName"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/TextViewLabelName"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/TextViewLabelName" />

        <TextView
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/TextViewTitle1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:text="@string/title_1"
            android:layout_below="@id/TextViewLabelName" />

        <View
            android:background="#000000"
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_centerVertical ="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/TextViewTitle1" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100.0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_separator"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/TextViewTitle1"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/TextViewTitle1"
            android:layout_below="@id/TextViewTitle1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

            <!-- This is the TextView I'm having trouble with. -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextViewInfo1"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100.0dip"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:ems="10"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_info_1"
                android:background="@drawable/style_edittext" />
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/RelativeLayoutMain"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_1" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_2" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_3" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this in the textview in which you want the scroll

android:maxLines="25"
 android:scrollbars="vertical"

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100.0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_separator"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/TextViewTitle1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/TextViewTitle1"
        android:layout_below="@id/TextViewTitle1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <!-- This is the TextView I'm having trouble with. -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextViewInfo1"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:maxLines="25"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:ems="10"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_info_1"
            android:background="@drawable/style_edittext" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

And in code :

```
yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod())
```

do this.It should work

**Edit**

This method is for replacing the ScrollView. ScrollView and TextView don't go together well atleast that was in my case.Forget to mention that in the answer.Replace the ScrollView with any other container like RelativeLayout or LinearLayout

Comment: It's not working; it still just looks the same. I should point out the TextView I'm talking about is the one with ID "TextViewInfo1" (I edited my question to make it clear). Also, its background gives it a border, so it's easy to see when the TextView shrinks.

Comment: Never mind. I just realized the problem was lying in the ScrollView. I replaced it for a RelativeLayout and it worked. You should probably edit your answer to indicate the ScrollView has to be changed, but otherwise your answer is perfect.

Comment: Sorry I forget to mention that see my edits ...Accept the answer as well if it helped you to solve the problem :)